# Mobile portrait and landscape versions exactly the same

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

@media for portrait and landscape don't seem to change when using Bootstrap for this website: http://moodisorder.com

Can anyone please explain how I might have this site respond to single column for portrait on a mobile device, and same as desktop version for landscape on mobile device.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters under moodisorder.com you have not declared the viewport, so you must add the meta viewport  there, like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Now under site the georgehowell.biz/sk/ there's a meta viewport, but you are pulling this website's content into moodisorcer.com via frameset, like so:

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://georgehowell.biz/sk/" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
```

I have never used a frameset or iframe to pull content as you are trying to do, but setting the "rows="100%,*" with the additional param in "noresize" to the frame might prove to be the issue.  This might be obstructing Bootstrap from doing its job.

Comment: thanks @marcelo-martins. You solved this via something so simple, I'd over-looked it. The host had another IP address to the one where my files were stored, so it was re-directing via that yuky frameset index out there somewhere. 
Now "viewsource:moodisorder.com" is as it should be
Thanks heaps!!

Comment: You're welcome! I am glad to help and I'll will looking at the fix, as well.  I am interested in the final result too!

Comment: http://moodisorder.com/assets/css/styles.css is now working fine, on top of the Bootstrap grid (I was going in circles before you helped me). 
"Mobile/Responsive Web Design Tester" Chrome extension is great for testing in every variation, portrait and landscape. Half an hours work when all runs well. Do you prefer "Firebug"?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to play with media queries, and when writing media query you can define, `orientation:portrait` , or `orientation:landscape` and apply css accordingly.

Comment: Hi Sanjeev. Thanks for your comment. Dr Sanjeev Gupta gave me a new hip three weeks ago, so I have another three weeks to finish learning AngularJS